# How to calculate the distance between an isosceles triangle that lies on the tangent of the circle and its projected shadow on the circle?

Tags: math, trigonometry

I'll try to describe my issue as well as I can.

I have an isosceles triangle that is touching a circle on its tangent.
The point of intersection between the two is exactly at the mid-point of the base of the triangle.

If you were to prolong the two sides of the triangle (purple sides on the picture) from the tangent line of the circle to the intersection of circle, and draw a horizontal line from one intersection to the other and creating a parallel line to the base of the original triangle, there would be a distance between these two parallel lines (orange line), that is the distance I need to find.

The triangle has height h = 4.0, base c = 2.294
The circle is r = 5.0

[setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL03F.jpg)

If the opposite side was just some straight solid, it would fairly be easy to calculate with basic trigonometry, but because the opposite side is actually a curve, I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: This is a maths question. It will probably just get closed here. I would start by working out the equation of the line of one of the sides of the triangle, then use that to get a quadratic equation for the distance of a point on that line from the circle centre. That should give you the answer at r=5.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.
Ask, instead, on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Circle (centered at 0,0)
x^2 + y^2 = 25
y = sqrt(25 - x^2) (we only care about the positive root)

Triangle - left side:
points: (x1, y1) = (-2.294,5); (x2, y2) = (0, 9)
m = slope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) = 4 / 2.294 = 1.74367916303
b = intercept = 9
y = 1.74367916303 * x + 9

Intersection:
sqrt(25 - x^2) = 1.74367916303 * x + 9
square both sides: 25 - x^2 = 3.04041702359 x^2 + 31.3862249345 x + 81
4.04041702359 x^2 + 31.3862249345 x + 56 = 0
Solve for x using the quadratic formula:
x = [-2.7768943112438587, -4.991171398620081]
```

There are two points of intersection because the line intersects the circle twice. We want the higher one.

```
y = 1.74367916303 * -2.7768943112438587 + 9
y = 4.15798725155
```

We compare that to the base of the original triangle which is at y=5 (radius of the circle up from the origin), and get the vertical distance between the two to be:

```
5 - 4.15798725155 = 0.84201274845
```

Comment: The question is off topic. Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]